# Where to find "clear all" icon Android 4.1+ have in the notification bar

Tags: android, android-resources

[image: clear all]

I have been searching the net and looking through the assets in the SDK but I cannot find the "clear all" icon (se above). Does anyone know what the name of the resource is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**normal:**

> [image: normal clear all]

**pressed:**

> [image: pressed clear all]

The "clear all" icon is called `ic_notify_clear_normal.png`. Along with other status bar icons, such as opening the quick settings, it is part of the `SystemUI` package and located in the source under `[android source]/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/res/drawable-*/`.

You can browse the latest source here: http://androidxref.com/source/xref/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/res/drawable-xhdpi/